# .findIndex is not function failed on unitest Jasmine

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine

My code is like

```
const array2 = [
  { id: 1, dev: false },
  { id: 2, dev: false },
  { id: 3, dev: true }
];
const search = obj => obj.dev === true;
console.log(array2.findIndex(search));
```

I want to find index of dev: true, I got correct index but failed for unit test Jasmine it's make all the test case in spec file fail. the error said .findIndex is not a function

Comment: Most probably between unit cases you have lost the value of array2, which now does not hold an array

Comment: Change findIndex as follows  `array2.findIndex((val:any)=>val.dev===true)`

Comment: still not working even I try to check if array2 is not null or [] then should call .findIndex

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.